# What are the possibilities to add souce documentation on a module/folder level?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, markdown, docstring

In iOS/Xcode projects it's common to use docstrings with Markdown for documenting methods, properties, protocols etc. within one source file.

However, I couldn't find any proper way for documenting a "folder" of files. E.g. I have sorted my app's functionality in different folders ("Xcode groups") and would like to attach some documentation on that level. For example that one folder is responsible for Network authentication, which is represented by more than just one source file.

How can that be achieved in such a way that we can always regenerate the current documentation with a tool such as Jazzy?

Answer (score 0):

Jazzy do not document files based on folder. It creates Apple like documentation, in which left hand side it names file in alphabetically order.

The only thing you need to do generate document is to comment your code properly. Jazzy parse your comment and creates document for it.

Jazzy can be installed by using this command in terminal

```
[sudo] gem install jazzy
```

You need to provide minimum access specifier to jazzy

```
jazzy --min-acl internal
```

here internal is access specifier, you can provide **private** if you want include private files for documentation.

jazzy command compiles you code then it creates document for it. Make sure your code compiles before creating document.

Please refer this document:-
https://medium.com/@_kenny/framework-friday-jazzy-c214fb9a5890

Comment: Thanks, but you say `Jazzy do not document files based on folder.` This is what I want. I know what Jazzy can do on file level, but I want something one level up, basically, where I can describe the app structures, modules, and how everything is put together, so a new developer doesn't have to consult external documentation and wikis to get an overview.

Comment: I just figured out that Jazzy supports a `--documentation` option to include more Markdown files. I think this is the thing I was looking for…